# Temporary variable within list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

It happens to me quite often to have a piece of code that looks like this.

```
raw_data  = [(s.split(',')[0], s.split(',')[1]) for s in all_lines if s.split(',')[1] != '"NaN"']
```

Basically, I'd like to know if there is a way to create a temporary variable like `splitted_s` in order to avoid having to repeat operations on the looped object (like, in this case, having to split it three times).

Comment: `lambda` function? Maybe something like that: `temp = lambda x, i: x.split(',')[i]`

Comment: You could roll that right into the list comp with `[s[:2] for s in map(lambda x: x.split(','), all_lines) if s[1] != '"Nan"']`.

Comment: If I had to split the same string three times I would not use a comprehension

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have two actions for processing, you may embed another list comprehension:

```
raw_data  = [(lhs, rhs) 
            for lhs, rhs 
            in [s.split(',')[:2] for s in all_lines]
            if rhs != '"NaN"']
```

You can use generator inside (it gives a small performance gain too):

```
            in (s.split(',')[:2] for s in all_lines)
```

It will even be faster than your implementation:

```
import timeit

setup = '''import random, string;
all_lines = [','.join((random.choice(string.letters),
                    str(random.random() if random.random() > 0.3 else '"NaN"')))
                    for i in range(10000)]'''
oneloop = '''[(s.split(',')[0], s.split(',')[1]) 
              for s in all_lines if s.split(',')[1] != '"NaN"']'''
twoloops = '''raw_data  = [(lhs, rhs) 
                for lhs, rhs 
                in [s.split(',') for s in all_lines]
                if rhs != '"NaN"']'''

timeit.timeit(oneloop, setup, number=1000)  # 7.77 secs
timeit.timeit(twoloops, setup, number=1000) # 4.68 secs
```

Comment: This only works if `split` produces 2 items. Also, inner list comprehension could be a generator.

Comment: @tobias_k: I've updated my answer. Speaking of generator, it gave me 4.49 secs in my test ;)

Comment: Try `s.split(',', 2)`

Answer (score 18):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), it's possible to use a local variable within a list comprehension in order to avoid calling twice the same expression:

In our case, we can name the evaluation of `line.split(',')` as a variable `parts` while using the result of the expression to filter the list if `parts[1]` is not equal to `NaN`; and thus re-use `parts` to produce the mapped value:

```
# lines = ['1,2,3,4', '5,NaN,7,8']
[(parts[0], parts[1]) for line in lines if (parts := line.split(','))[1] != 'NaN']
# [('1', '2')]
```

Comment: What if there is no `if`` condition; is there a way to still assign to the temporary variable?

Comment: @ElRudi I'm not sure what temporary variable you're referring to, but any expression can be assigned to a variable, whether it's part of a condition or not.

Comment: Thanks for that fast reply. I meant that, in your answer, you assign `line.split(',')` to (what I called 'temporary variable') `parts`, and you do this as part of the `if` condition in the comprehension. You are then able to reuse `parts` in the tuple. Is it possible to make the same assignment to `parts` if no such if-condition is present? So, when the original question would have been to rewrite `raw_data  = [(s.split(',')[0], s.split(',')[1]) for s in all_lines]`.

Comment: @ElRudi Oh I see, yeah you could do something like: `[((parts := line.split(','))[0], parts[1]) for line in lines]`. It feels a bit more difficult to read, the assignment in the if condition made it a bit clearer.

Comment: When there is more than one condition in `if`, you can do `[c for c in candidates if (x := c.upper()) != w and Counter(x) == freq]`

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

> A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses. The result will be a new list resulting from evaluating the expression in the context of the for and if clauses which follow it.

[From here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Assignment in Python is not an expression.

As Padraic Cunningham comments - if you need to split it multiple times don't do it in list comprehension.

Comment: You can't *assign* in a list comp, sure, but you can certainly have `splitted_s` available inside, using e.g. `for splitted_s in map(lambda x: x.split(','), all_lines)`.