# How to simplify a list comprehension of distributions in python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

Get objects for continuous distributions in scipy.stats
This is the sample code:
getditributions.py

```
import scipy.stats as st


CONTINUOUS_DISTRIBUTIONS = [getattr(st,d) for d in dir(st) if isinstance(getattr(st,d), st.rv_continuous)]

print ('number of distributions = ', len(CONTINUOUS_DISTRIBUTIONS))

print ('CONTINUOUS_DISTRIBUTIONS = ')
print(CONTINUOUS_ DISTRIBUTIONS)
```

Obs: This code works but I have called getattr twice in the list comprehension.
How to simplify this code to have just one call to getattr? Or alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular `for-loop`.

**Ex:**

```
CONTINUOUS_DISTRIBUTIONS = []
for d in dir(st):
    val = getattr(st,d)     #Store in variable for re-use.
    if isinstance(val, st.rv_continuous):
        CONTINUOUS_DISTRIBUTIONS.append(val)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well! A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses. No way to use val in list comprehension. From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820026/temporary-variable-within-list-comprehension?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Yes you are correct. You cannot have a variable in a list comprehension.