# Python transform and filter list with for / if

Tags: python

Is there a way to both transform and filter in a single list comprehension, i.e.:

```py
def transform(el):
    if some_condition(el):
        return None

    return complex_logic(el)

def main():
    transformed = [transform(el) for el in some_list if transform(el) != None]
```

but avoid calling `transform` twice? I.e. assign it to a variable, something like (in pseudo-Python):

```
def main():
  transformed = [transformed for el in some_list let transformed = transform(el) if transformed != None]
```

Comment: The reason you're having trouble is that `transform` violates the single responsibility principle -- doing the transformation *and* the filtering might seem like it would make your code simpler by giving you one function to call, but it's actually making it more complicated.  Just get rid of `transform` entirely and do `transformed = [complex_logic(el) for el in some_list if some_condition(el)]`.

Comment: I would say no unless you allow `filter(map())` combo. I would argue in some cases using list comprehension is counter to clear/optimal code.

Comment: @Samwise Thanks, that's a fair point for this example. I'm not sure if it will be that easy though, since the real code has a bunch of steps and each step has various conditions which can result in either `None` being returned or the transformation continuing forward. Think about processing XML with deep structure and having a condition at every node. Your recommendation would likely result in a lot of duplication between `complex_logic` and `some_condition` functions, which while it could bring clarity I'm not sure is a net win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Python 3.8 you can use [*walrus* operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) `:=`:

```py
def main():
    return [res for el in some_list if (res := transform(el)) is not None]
```

This way the result of calling to the `transform` function is stored in `res` then you can use it in the expression part of your list comprehension.

Comment: Interesting, did not know about `:=`, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Replace `let transformed = transform(el)` with `for transformed in [transform(el)]`.

Comment: Thanks, that's on the border of being 1- and 2-comprehension solution! :)

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary No, it's perfectly fine the way it is. Note that this is "[the idiom for assignment a temporary variable in comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations)" that's even optimized to be a simple assignment. It doesn't actually build a list.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary It's exactly the OP's line with my replacement: `[transformed for el in some_list for transformed in [transform(el)] if transformed != None]`.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary Although in reality I might use `map`, i.e., `[transformed for transformed in map(transform, some_list) if transformed != None]`. Or `:=` like you've shown (its possible disadvantage of leaking the variable doesn't really matter in a `return` statement). I just tried to stay as close as possible to their "pseudo-Python".

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary Btw [the story behind](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/77037) it is interesting, too, its history is closely related to the history of `:=`.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary Hmm, maybe you need less thinking for the walrus just because you're more used to it? I'm pretty used to both, and I don't find one requiring more or less thinking than the other.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the solution from simple, over idiomatic to readable:

#### Simple loop with temp var

The simple but verbose for-loop can be used to "cache" the transformation result in a temporary variable `t`:

```py
def transform(el):
    if some_condition(el):
        return None
    return complex_logic(el)


def main():
    transformed_list = []
    for el in some_list:
        t = transform(el)  # invoked once
        if t is not None:  # equivalent to `if transform(el) != None`
            transformed_list.append(t)
```

#### Embedded List Comprehension

Like [Kelly Bundy suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72133856/5730279), embed the list-comprehensions:

1. transformation of elements
2. filter for non-null

See also [Temporary variable within list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820026/temporary-variable-within-list-comprehension)

#### Decouple condition from transformation

[Command–query separation (CQS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation#Command_Query_Responsibility_Separation) can be applied

> to have a simplifying effect on a program, making its states (via queries) and state changes (via commands) more comprehensible.

Assume the 2 given functions (`some_condition` and `complex_logic`) were separately defined because each implements a [single-responsibility (SRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). Then it would be consequential to take advantage of this separation and reuse the 2 steps in suitable composition:

1. Query: by [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) first using the condition function as *predicate*
2. Command: afterwards to *transform* by complex logic

This way the pipeline or stream might even become more readable:

```
transformed = [complex_logic(el) for el in filter(some_condition, some_list)]
```

Finally this is close to what [Samwise advised in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133777/python-transform-and-filter-list-with-for-if#comment127452863_72133777): Now the SRP is followed.

Comment: Just to note, in your first solution, you need to change `if t:` to `if t is not None:` because they are not the same. With `if t:`, falsy values like `0` are not gonna append to the list.